# Split a dataframe into a list of nested data frames and matrices

Tags: r, database, list, matrix, dplyr

I'd like to split the `diamonds` data frame into a list of 5 dataframe, group by `cut`. This instruction got me started.
https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_split.html

```
diamonds_g <- diamonds%>% group_split(cut)%>% setNames(unique(diamonds$cut))
```

My desired output is a list of 5 nested lists. Each nested list contains one data frame and one matrix, such that:

```
View(diamonds_g[[1]])
factors <- diamonds_g[[1]][2:4]
mat <- diamonds_g[[1]][6:10]
```

So each of the nested list (or each `cut`) contains one data frame of n rows (depending on how many diamonds are classified as that cut) named factors by 3 columns, and one matrix of n rows by 10 columns named mat. In other words, the lowest level of the list (the nested matrix and data frame) should have identical names across the 5 nested lists. How do I proceed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
result <- lapply(diamonds_g, function(x) 
                 list(factors = x[2:4], mat = as.matrix(x[6:10])))
```

Comment: It looks like it is. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
result <- map(diamonds_g, ~ list(factors = .x[2:4], mat = as.matrix(.x[6:10])))
```