# Split a large data frame in to a nested list and only keep meaningful non-grouping factors in R

Tags: r, dplyr

This is a complex follow up to this question [Split a dataframe into a list of nested data frames and matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65120387/split-a-dataframe-into-a-list-of-nested-data-frames-and-matrices)
I now split the original data frame with 2 grouping variables. I can't find an unbalanced dataset so I'll just put the code and screenshot.

Here is a representative subset of the data

```
> dput(dat2)
structure(list(`2017/2-year` = structure(list(Side = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("E", 
"W"), class = "factor"), Crop = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("alfalfa", 
"corn", "oat", "soybean"), class = "factor"), Rotation.treatment = structure(c(7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A4", 
"C2", "C3", "C4", "O3", "O4", "S2", "S3", "S4"), class = "factor"), 
    Herb = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("conv", "low"), class = "factor"), 
    hist_Herb = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("conv", "low"), class = "factor"), 
    CF = c(18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 
    18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 
    18.532), Year = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L), Rot_n = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Rot = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2-year", 
    "3-year", "4-year"), class = "factor"), ID.y = structure(c(49L, 
    49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 13L, 9L, 9L, 13L, 13L, 
    9L, 13L, 9L), .Label = c("A4_conv_2017", "A4_conv_2018", 
    "A4_CONV_2019", "A4_CONV_2020", "A4_low_2017", "A4_low_2018", 
    "A4_LOW_2019", "A4_LOW_2020", "C2_conv_2017", "C2_conv_2018", 
    "C2_CONV_2019", "C2_CONV_2020", "C2_low_2017", "C2_low_2018", 
    "C2_LOW_2019", "C2_LOW_2020", "C3_conv_2017", "C3_conv_2018", 
    "C3_CONV_2019", "C3_CONV_2020", "C3_low_2017", "C3_low_2018", 
    "C3_LOW_2019", "C3_LOW_2020", "C4_conv_2017", "C4_conv_2018", 
    "C4_CONV_2019", "C4_CONV_2020", "C4_low_2017", "C4_low_2018", 
    "C4_LOW_2019", "C4_LOW_2020", "O3_conv_2017", "O3_conv_2018", 
    "O3_CONV_2019", "O3_CONV_2020", "O3_low_2017", "O3_low_2018", 
    "O3_LOW_2019", "O3_LOW_2020", "O4_conv_2017", "O4_conv_2018", 
    "O4_CONV_2019", "O4_CONV_2020", "O4_low_2017", "O4_low_2018", 
    "O4_LOW_2019", "O4_LOW_2020", "S2_conv_2017", "S2_conv_2018", 
    "S2_conv_2019", "S2_conv_2020", "S3_conv_2017", "S3_conv_2018", 
    "S3_conv_2019", "S3_conv_2020", "S4_conv_2017", "S4_conv_2018", 
    "S4_conv_2019", "S4_conv_2020"), class = "factor"), ID = structure(c(25L, 
    25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 
    7L, 5L), .Label = c("A4_conv", "A4_CONV", "A4_low", "A4_LOW", 
    "C2_conv", "C2_CONV", "C2_low", "C2_LOW", "C3_conv", "C3_CONV", 
    "C3_low", "C3_LOW", "C4_conv", "C4_CONV", "C4_low", "C4_LOW", 
    "O3_conv", "O3_CONV", "O3_low", "O3_LOW", "O4_conv", "O4_CONV", 
    "O4_low", "O4_LOW", "S2_conv", "S3_conv", "S4_conv"), class = "factor"), 
    Block = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("rep1", "rep2", "rep3", 
    "rep4"), class = "factor"), group_name = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("2017/2-year", "2017/3-year", "2017/4-year", 
    "2018/2-year", "2018/3-year", "2018/4-year", "2019/2-year", 
    "2019/3-year", "2019/4-year", "2020/2-year", "2020/3-year", 
    "2020/4-year"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -16L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2017/3-year` = structure(list(
    Side = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("E", 
    "W"), class = "factor"), Crop = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("alfalfa", "corn", "oat", "soybean"
    ), class = "factor"), Rotation.treatment = structure(c(8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("A4", "C2", "C3", 
    "C4", "O3", "O4", "S2", "S3", "S4"), class = "factor"), Herb = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("conv", "low"), class = "factor"), 
    hist_Herb = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("conv", 
    "low"), class = "factor"), CF = c(18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 
    18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 
    18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 2.24, 2.24, 2.24, 2.24, 2.24, 
    2.24, 2.24, 2.24), Year = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L
    ), Rot_n = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Rot = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2-year", "3-year", 
    "4-year"), class = "factor"), ID.y = structure(c(53L, 53L, 
    53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 17L, 21L, 17L, 21L, 17L, 21L, 21L, 
    17L, 33L, 37L, 33L, 37L, 37L, 33L, 33L, 37L), .Label = c("A4_conv_2017", 
    "A4_conv_2018", "A4_CONV_2019", "A4_CONV_2020", "A4_low_2017", 
    "A4_low_2018", "A4_LOW_2019", "A4_LOW_2020", "C2_conv_2017", 
    "C2_conv_2018", "C2_CONV_2019", "C2_CONV_2020", "C2_low_2017", 
    "C2_low_2018", "C2_LOW_2019", "C2_LOW_2020", "C3_conv_2017", 
    "C3_conv_2018", "C3_CONV_2019", "C3_CONV_2020", "C3_low_2017", 
    "C3_low_2018", "C3_LOW_2019", "C3_LOW_2020", "C4_conv_2017", 
    "C4_conv_2018", "C4_CONV_2019", "C4_CONV_2020", "C4_low_2017", 
    "C4_low_2018", "C4_LOW_2019", "C4_LOW_2020", "O3_conv_2017", 
    "O3_conv_2018", "O3_CONV_2019", "O3_CONV_2020", "O3_low_2017", 
    "O3_low_2018", "O3_LOW_2019", "O3_LOW_2020", "O4_conv_2017", 
    "O4_conv_2018", "O4_CONV_2019", "O4_CONV_2020", "O4_low_2017", 
    "O4_low_2018", "O4_LOW_2019", "O4_LOW_2020", "S2_conv_2017", 
    "S2_conv_2018", "S2_conv_2019", "S2_conv_2020", "S3_conv_2017", 
    "S3_conv_2018", "S3_conv_2019", "S3_conv_2020", "S4_conv_2017", 
    "S4_conv_2018", "S4_conv_2019", "S4_conv_2020"), class = "factor"), 
    ID = structure(c(26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 9L, 11L, 
    9L, 11L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 9L, 17L, 19L, 17L, 19L, 19L, 17L, 
    17L, 19L), .Label = c("A4_conv", "A4_CONV", "A4_low", "A4_LOW", 
    "C2_conv", "C2_CONV", "C2_low", "C2_LOW", "C3_conv", "C3_CONV", 
    "C3_low", "C3_LOW", "C4_conv", "C4_CONV", "C4_low", "C4_LOW", 
    "O3_conv", "O3_CONV", "O3_low", "O3_LOW", "O4_conv", "O4_CONV", 
    "O4_low", "O4_LOW", "S2_conv", "S3_conv", "S4_conv"), class = "factor"), 
    Block = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("rep1", 
    "rep2", "rep3", "rep4"), class = "factor"), group_name = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2017/2-year", "2017/3-year", 
    "2017/4-year", "2018/2-year", "2018/3-year", "2018/4-year", 
    "2019/2-year", "2019/3-year", "2019/4-year", "2020/2-year", 
    "2020/3-year", "2020/4-year"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-23L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2017/4-year` = structure(list(
    Side = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("E", "W"), class = "factor"), 
    Crop = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("alfalfa", "corn", 
    "oat", "soybean"), class = "factor"), Rotation.treatment = structure(c(9L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("A4", "C2", "C3", "C4", "O3", "O4", "S2", 
    "S3", "S4"), class = "factor"), Herb = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("conv", "low"), class = "factor"), hist_Herb = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L), .Label = c("conv", "low"), class = "factor"), CF = c(18.532, 
    18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 
    18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 18.532, 2.24, 
    2.24, 2.24, 2.24, 2.24, 2.24, 2.24, 2.24, 2.24, 2.24, 2.24, 
    2.24, 2.24, 2.24, 2.24, 2.24), Year = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L), Rot_n = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), Rot = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L), .Label = c("2-year", "3-year", "4-year"), class = "factor"), 
    ID.y = structure(c(57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 
    29L, 25L, 25L, 29L, 29L, 25L, 29L, 25L, 41L, 45L, 5L, 1L, 
    45L, 41L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 41L, 45L, 41L, 45L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("A4_conv_2017", 
    "A4_conv_2018", "A4_CONV_2019", "A4_CONV_2020", "A4_low_2017", 
    "A4_low_2018", "A4_LOW_2019", "A4_LOW_2020", "C2_conv_2017", 
    "C2_conv_2018", "C2_CONV_2019", "C2_CONV_2020", "C2_low_2017", 
    "C2_low_2018", "C2_LOW_2019", "C2_LOW_2020", "C3_conv_2017", 
    "C3_conv_2018", "C3_CONV_2019", "C3_CONV_2020", "C3_low_2017", 
    "C3_low_2018", "C3_LOW_2019", "C3_LOW_2020", "C4_conv_2017", 
    "C4_conv_2018", "C4_CONV_2019", "C4_CONV_2020", "C4_low_2017", 
    "C4_low_2018", "C4_LOW_2019", "C4_LOW_2020", "O3_conv_2017", 
    "O3_conv_2018", "O3_CONV_2019", "O3_CONV_2020", "O3_low_2017", 
    "O3_low_2018", "O3_LOW_2019", "O3_LOW_2020", "O4_conv_2017", 
    "O4_conv_2018", "O4_CONV_2019", "O4_CONV_2020", "O4_low_2017", 
    "O4_low_2018", "O4_LOW_2019", "O4_LOW_2020", "S2_conv_2017", 
    "S2_conv_2018", "S2_conv_2019", "S2_conv_2020", "S3_conv_2017", 
    "S3_conv_2018", "S3_conv_2019", "S3_conv_2020", "S4_conv_2017", 
    "S4_conv_2018", "S4_conv_2019", "S4_conv_2020"), class = "factor"), 
    ID = structure(c(27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
    15L, 13L, 13L, 15L, 15L, 13L, 15L, 13L, 21L, 23L, 3L, 1L, 
    23L, 21L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 21L, 23L, 21L, 23L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("A4_conv", 
    "A4_CONV", "A4_low", "A4_LOW", "C2_conv", "C2_CONV", "C2_low", 
    "C2_LOW", "C3_conv", "C3_CONV", "C3_low", "C3_LOW", "C4_conv", 
    "C4_CONV", "C4_low", "C4_LOW", "O3_conv", "O3_CONV", "O3_low", 
    "O3_LOW", "O4_conv", "O4_CONV", "O4_low", "O4_LOW", "S2_conv", 
    "S3_conv", "S4_conv"), class = "factor"), Block = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L), .Label = c("rep1", "rep2", "rep3", "rep4"), class = "factor"), 
    group_name = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("2017/2-year", 
    "2017/3-year", "2017/4-year", "2018/2-year", "2018/3-year", 
    "2018/4-year", "2019/2-year", "2019/3-year", "2019/4-year", 
    "2020/2-year", "2020/3-year", "2020/4-year"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-32L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))), ptype = structure(list(
    Side = structure(integer(0), .Label = c("E", "W"), class = "factor"), 
    Crop = structure(integer(0), .Label = c("alfalfa", "corn", 
    "oat", "soybean"), class = "factor"), Rotation.treatment = structure(integer(0), .Label = c("A4", 
    "C2", "C3", "C4", "O3", "O4", "S2", "S3", "S4"), class = "factor"), 
    Herb = structure(integer(0), .Label = c("conv", "low"), class = "factor"), 
    hist_Herb = structure(integer(0), .Label = c("conv", "low"
    ), class = "factor"), CF = numeric(0), Year = integer(0), 
    Rot_n = integer(0), Rot = structure(integer(0), .Label = c("2-year", 
    "3-year", "4-year"), class = "factor"), ID.y = structure(integer(0), .Label = c("A4_conv_2017", 
    "A4_conv_2018", "A4_CONV_2019", "A4_CONV_2020", "A4_low_2017", 
    "A4_low_2018", "A4_LOW_2019", "A4_LOW_2020", "C2_conv_2017", 
    "C2_conv_2018", "C2_CONV_2019", "C2_CONV_2020", "C2_low_2017", 
    "C2_low_2018", "C2_LOW_2019", "C2_LOW_2020", "C3_conv_2017", 
    "C3_conv_2018", "C3_CONV_2019", "C3_CONV_2020", "C3_low_2017", 
    "C3_low_2018", "C3_LOW_2019", "C3_LOW_2020", "C4_conv_2017", 
    "C4_conv_2018", "C4_CONV_2019", "C4_CONV_2020", "C4_low_2017", 
    "C4_low_2018", "C4_LOW_2019", "C4_LOW_2020", "O3_conv_2017", 
    "O3_conv_2018", "O3_CONV_2019", "O3_CONV_2020", "O3_low_2017", 
    "O3_low_2018", "O3_LOW_2019", "O3_LOW_2020", "O4_conv_2017", 
    "O4_conv_2018", "O4_CONV_2019", "O4_CONV_2020", "O4_low_2017", 
    "O4_low_2018", "O4_LOW_2019", "O4_LOW_2020", "S2_conv_2017", 
    "S2_conv_2018", "S2_conv_2019", "S2_conv_2020", "S3_conv_2017", 
    "S3_conv_2018", "S3_conv_2019", "S3_conv_2020", "S4_conv_2017", 
    "S4_conv_2018", "S4_conv_2019", "S4_conv_2020"), class = "factor"), 
    ID = structure(integer(0), .Label = c("A4_conv", "A4_CONV", 
    "A4_low", "A4_LOW", "C2_conv", "C2_CONV", "C2_low", "C2_LOW", 
    "C3_conv", "C3_CONV", "C3_low", "C3_LOW", "C4_conv", "C4_CONV", 
    "C4_low", "C4_LOW", "O3_conv", "O3_CONV", "O3_low", "O3_LOW", 
    "O4_conv", "O4_CONV", "O4_low", "O4_LOW", "S2_conv", "S3_conv", 
    "S4_conv"), class = "factor"), Block = structure(integer(0), .Label = c("rep1", 
    "rep2", "rep3", "rep4"), class = "factor"), group_name = structure(integer(0), .Label = c("2017/2-year", 
    "2017/3-year", "2017/4-year", "2018/2-year", "2018/3-year", 
    "2018/4-year", "2019/2-year", "2019/3-year", "2019/4-year", 
    "2020/2-year", "2020/3-year", "2020/4-year"), class = "factor")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = integer(0)), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))
```

Here is the desired output:
The `Crop` factor in the original data set has 4 levels. Once split by `group_name`, any dataframe that is 2017/2-year should have 2 levels of `Crop`, 2017/3-year should have 3 levels of `Crop` and 2017/4-year 4 levels of `Crop`. The current splitter list have 4 levels of crops in all nested list not the actual. Here is the conflict.

Split data seen by `View()` with all the levels of `Crop`
[image]

Split data with the actual levels of `Crop` (2) for 2017/2-year
[image]

Here is the code that produced the result above. How do I change it? Thank you!

```
data$group_name <-  factor(paste(data$Year, data$Rot, sep='/'))
weed_r_y_list <- data %>% group_split(group_name) %>%
   setNames(unique(data$group_name))
```

Comment: Please make your problem reproducible so it's easier to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep `Crop` column as factors then one way would be to turn them to factor again so that the levels are arranged based on the data in the list now.

```
result <- lapply(dat2, function(x) {x$Crop <- factor(x$Crop);x})
```

We could check the `levels` now in the `result`.

```
levels(dat2$`2017/2-year`$Crop)
#[1] "alfalfa" "corn"    "oat"     "soybean"

levels(result$`2017/2-year`$Crop)
#[1] "corn"    "soybean"

levels(dat2$`2017/3-year`$Crop)
#[1] "alfalfa" "corn"    "oat"     "soybean"

levels(result$`2017/3-year`$Crop)
#[1] "corn"    "oat"     "soybean"
```